# Different Ways to Bind a popstate Event

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser-history, history.js

What is the difference between these three events?

**1**

```
 $(window).bind("popstate", function() {
     alert('popstate');
 });
```

**2**

```
 window.onpopstate =  function() {
     alert('popstate');
 }
```

**3**

```
window.addEventListener("popstate", function (event){
    if (event.state) {
        alert('popstate');
    }
});
```

Comment: There is no difference. They're all the same event. The first uses jQuery (a JavaScript library) to bind the event, and 2 & 3 use vanilla javascript (no library) to do it.

Comment: Can i use 1st event like 3rd example?

Comment: They're the same `popstate` event. Just different ways of binding them. If you don't want to use jQuery, then use example 2/3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no difference. All three are binding listeners to the `popstate` event. The first one uses the jQuery library, while the other two are vanilla JS.

One small exception - the second method will **replace** any previous `popstate` event listener, while the other ones will just **add** a new one.